# Avoid empty option element from multiselect box

Tags: zend-form

I am using `Zend form` and using it i am creating a multi select box. But when the multiselect box is created the first option value is a empty element.. like this

```
`<option value=""></option>`
```

I want to avoid this..This is the code i am using..

```
$addressType_selected = $this>createElement('multiselect','addressType_selected[]')                                
                      -> setAttrib('class','float_left input_width_295  k-multiselectbx')
                      -> setAttrib('tabindex',43);
$addressType_selected->setDecorators(array(
                                          'ViewHelper',     
                                          'Errors'
                                     ));
```

What is wrong with my code.. i am stuck with this... Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer..
Just used the following script

```
$("#addressType_selected option[value='']").remove();
```